# Getting text from a specific object using Visual Studio / Test Complete (14) and object spy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some text I want to get (number of rows and total number of rows). see picture:

[image]

I used object spy and have this:

[image]

If I have the object in a var, how can I extract the text from it (using C#).  Something like in selenium: *text = ele.getText()* (if ele is the element we are talking about).  This is MS Windows (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

you may have to get the instance of text node to do that.